# LWC suddenly fails to load library from static resource

Tags: lightning-web-components, fullcalendar

I recently implemented a LWC that uses the FullCalendar.io library. Yesterday, one of my users reached out because the component is not working anymore.

All other aspects of the LWC work just fine, but the calendar itself is not initialized. After digging around for a bit, I found that the static resource that contains the library is not being loaded.

```
    async renderedCallback() {
    await this.getUserResources();
    await this.getEventData();
    console.log('should appear after load');
    if (this.isCalInitialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.isCalInitialized = true;

    try {
        await Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, FULL_CALENDAR + '/main.min.js'),
            loadStyle(this, FULL_CALENDAR + '/main.min.css')
        ]);
        this.initializeCalendar();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

The output in the console just reads {}.

I originally found the framework for this component on https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsFullCalendar and one of the requirements there was to enable Lighning Web Security (which is enabled).

The really strange thing is that this component isn't working anywhere. Not in PROD, and not in our sandboxes. I spun up a fresh dev org and just deployed the basic version of the LWC recipe there, and it's not rendering there either.

Is anyone else running into something similar? I'm starting to think it's a general issue...

Comment: The Spring22 was globally upgraded 2 days ago. Not sure, if that's what causing the issue. Please check if any of the security/iframe related stuff are changed in this release.

Comment: @Frederik Pardon whats the static resource's status code when you try to load it?

Comment: I can see some recent commits related to Spring'22 in the above repositories made by Philippe Ozil and Satya Sekhar. Did you check the latest code if it is working. Try to reach out the authors at Twitter. These are their handles https://twitter.com/satyasfdc  https://twitter.com/PhilippeOzil

Comment: @glls What exactly do you mean by resource status code?

Comment: when your page loads in the browser, each request is accompanied by a status code - your browsers developer tools is the place to go to identify this, more specifically, the network tab. this way, you will have a better idea of why the library is not loaded.